# FFMPEG SRT video send only audio to icecast

Tags: ffmpeg, icecast, srt

So I know that with FFMPEG you can read `srt://` Now I now you can also take a video and turn it into audio only.

But the problem we are having is

- We don't know how to only send the audio from a video `srt` to icecast server

Example RMPT stream to icecast:

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://192.168.22.12/live/live1 -vn \
       -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 64k -f mp3 \
       -content_type audio/mpeg \
       icecast://source:pass@example.com:8000/mountpoint.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i srt://hostname:port -vn \
       -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 64k -f mp3 \
       -content_type audio/mpeg \
       icecast://source:pass@example.com:8000/mountpoint.mp3
```

- Requires `ffmpeg` to be compiled with `--enable-libsrt`.
- See [FFmpeg SRT protocol documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#srt) and [FFmpeg icecast protocol documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#Icecast).